# R: How to merge a new data frame to several other data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge, lapply

I have several seperate data frames that I would like to keep separated because merging them together would create a very large element.

However, there are variables from another data frame that I would like to merge with all of them now.

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1:10), Var1 = rep(c(1,0),5))
df2 <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1:10), Var2 = c(21:30))

dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

mergewith <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1:10), ID2 = c(41:50))
```

My goal is that df1 and df2 will look like this:

```
df1

   ID1 Var1 ID2
1    1    1  41
2    2    0  42
3    3    1  43
4    4    0  44
5    5    1  45
6    6    0  46
7    7    1  47
8    8    0  48
9    9    1  49
10  10    0  50

df2 

ID1 Var2 ID2
1    1   21  41
2    2   22  42
3    3   23  43
4    4   24  44
5    5   25  45
6    6   26  46
7    7   27  47
8    8   28  48
9    9   29  49
10  10   30  50
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
dat = lapply(dfs,function(x){
  merge(names(x), mergewith, by = "ID1");x})
list2env(dat,.GlobalEnv)
```

However, then I get the following message:
"'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"

Is it possible to do this without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to `merge` all the dataframes in `dfs` with `mergewith`. Use `list2env` to get the changed dataframes in the global environment.

```
list2env(lapply(dfs, function(x) merge(x, mergewith, by = 'ID1')), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
When I run your code, I get the same error message, though:
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: @Nerd Can you try this in fresh R session? This works for me without any error for the data you have shared.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Map`

```
> Map(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "ID1"), dfs, list(mergewith))
[[1]]
   ID1 Var1 ID2
1    1    1  41
2    2    0  42
3    3    1  43
4    4    0  44
5    5    1  45
6    6    0  46
7    7    1  47
8    8    0  48
9    9    1  49
10  10    0  50

[[2]]
   ID1 Var2 ID2
1    1   21  41
2    2   22  42
3    3   23  43
4    4   24  44
5    5   25  45
6    6   26  46
7    7   27  47
8    8   28  48
9    9   29  49
10  10   30  50
```